# Is there a way to extract an element from a matrix using Quantmod?

Tags: r, extract, element

First time poster here and getting into R. I have a problem where I have to create a list "stocks" including two elements ; first element is a categorical vector with three stocks' ticker. Second element is a matrix with 5 rows and 3 columns. Each Column has the five days' market close price of one stock separately.

```
library(quantmod)

getSymbols(c("AMD","INTC","MU"), from = "2020-08-31", to="2020-9-5")
stocks = data.frame(cbind(AMD[,4], INTC[,4], MU[,4]))
getSymbols (c("AMD","INTC","MU"), from = "2020-08-31", to="2020-9-5")
x[2]

output:      INTC.Open INTC.High INTC.Low INTC.Close INTC.Volume INTC.Adjusted
2020-09-01     50.91        51    50.22      50.79    30522700         50.79

stocks
x[2]

           INTC.Close
2020-08-31      50.95
2020-09-01      50.79
2020-09-02      52.25
2020-09-03      50.39
2020-09-04      50.08
```

[image]

If I'm not mistaken, it should be the numeric value of $50.79  for the answer just unsure how to extract it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Would you mind checking the code block you posted in your question to be formatted in a more readable way? It seems to be going in and out of the code block and like this it's really hard for anyone to follow what is code and what is not.

Answer (score 2):

The `xts` object is a  `matrix` with attributes.

```
class(INTC[, "INTC.Close"])
#[1] "xts" "zoo"

is.matrix(INTC[, "INTC.Close"])
#[1] TRUE
```

We can use `as.numeric`

```
as.numeric(INTC[, "INTC.Close"][2])
#[1] 50.79
```

Or subset with the index date and the column name

```
as.numeric(INTC["2020-09-01", "INTC.Close"])
#[1] 50.79
```

Or with `as.vector`

```
as.vector(INTC["2020-09-01", "INTC.Close"])
#[1] 50.79
```

Comment: Thank you akrun!